# Comparing strings behaves different on mingw and on ubuntu gcc

Tags: c++, windows, string, ubuntu

I am trying to compare two strings. Here is the code that I have.

```
string line;
getline(cin, line);
if(line.compare("% Input alphabet")==0)
dosomething;
```

The problem is the following code works correctly when using mingw on a windows machine but when I run the same code on my ubuntu vm it does not execute dosomething method. I compiled my program and ran the following commands

On windows

> a.exe < input.txt

On Ubuntu

> ./a.out < input.txt

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the line endings (NL+CR vs NL).

Comment: Can you provide a small "input.txt" sample that would give these different results?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest trimming `\r\n` symbols at the end. That's the only difference between Window (\r\n) and Unix (\n).

Use `boost::trim()` to do that

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the exact same `input.txt` file that you created on Windows and then transferred to the Linux machine? If you are, then this might cause the problem you describe.

The idea is that C++ streams treat the line ending character differently based on platform (if you don't open the stream in binary mode). This line of code:

```
someTextFileStream << "some text\n";
```

if run on Windows will actually write `\r\n` at the end of the line and if run on Linux will only write `\n`.
The same is true when reading from text streams, on Windows `\r\n` will be interpreted as a single new line character/delimiter, on Linux only `\n` will be interpreted as the new line character.

Now if you create a text file on Windows (with Notepad for example), it will look something like this:

```
some text written on Windows\r\n
```

If you use `getline()` on Windows to read this, the string that `getline()` fills will contain `some text written on Windows`.

If you transfer this file exactly like this on Linux (so it is binary identical to the Windows file) and then read it using `getline()` again, the string will actually contain `some text written on Windows\r`. This is because on Linux the new line delimiter is `\n` and so `getline()` stops on that.

Possible solutions: trim the lines after reading them from the file; detect the line end delimiter and convert/handle it appropriately in your code; use proper line endings for the platform the code runs on when creating the file.